# Json_decode returns null at var_dump()

Tags: php, json

```
[
   {
      "CvePS":362544,
      "CveClasificacion":19893,
      "Clasificacion":"Clasificación de Prueba",
      "CveUM":4185,
      "CveUnidadMedida":4185,
      "UnidadMedida":"CAJA",
      "SATClaveUnidadMedida":"BB",
      "Codigo":"69H",
      "Codigo2":null,
      "CodigoBarras":null,
      "PS":"Prueba OC Nuevo4",
      "SATClavePS":null,
      "Precio":0,
      "CveTipoFactor":1,
      "Oferta":0,
      "CveSubFamilia":-1,
      "SubFamilia":"Sin Clasificación",
      "CostoPromedio":0.0000,
      "CveClasificacionPresupuesto":-1,
      "ClasificacionPresupuesto":"Sin Clasificación",
      "UsoClasificacion":3,
      "CvePuesto":null,
      "Puesto":null,
      "PSCodigo":"69H - Prueba OC Nuevo4",
      "PSCodigoCompuesto":"69H - Prueba OC Nuevo4",
      "IVA":-1,
      "RetIVA":0,
      "MargenGanancia":0,
      "IdCtaContVentas":0,
      "IdCtaContCompras":0,
      "IdCtaContInventarios":0,
      "AsientoContableVentas":1,
      "AsientoContableCompras":1,
      "AplicaParaConcepto":true,
      "AplicaParaVenta":true,
      "EsPaquete":false,
      "Estado":"Activo",
      "CveEstado":true,
      "Fecha":"\/Date(1547535600000)\/",
      "Usuario":"Sistema",
      "CveEmpresa":1,
      "CveMoneda":1,
      "Abreviatura":"MXN",
      "Moneda":"Pesos",
      "Inv_CveMetodoInventario":0,
      "CveTipoPS":2,
      "RowNum":1,
      "FuePorXML":1,
      "EsAdminPAQ":0,
      "PendienteEnOC":0,
      "CveClasificacionCosto":null,
      "AplicaSerieLote":null,
      "AplicaCaducidad":null,
      "Estado2":null,
      "CveClasificacion2":null,
      "AplicaParaVentaP":"Si",
      "Cantidad":1,
      "UnidadBase":true,
      "CveMarca":null,
      "AlmacenSeccion":null,
      "TipoPS":"Prod",
      "CvePSPaquete":null,
      "AplicaIEPS":false,
      "IEPSGrabaIVA":false,
      "IEPSPorcentaje":0,
      "CveConceptoContable":null,
      "CveCompuesto":-1,
      "CveSATPS":null,
      "SATClavePS1":null,
      "SATDescripcion":null,
      "Descripcion":null,
      "Inventariable":false,
      "CveProveedorCompra":null,
      "ProveedorCompra":null,
      "VentaMinima":null,
      "RetISR":null,
      "SATClaveProductoServicio":" - ",
      "PrecioMinimo":null,
      "CveFraccionArancelaria":null,
      "CveUnidadAduana":null,
      "ClaveSATFraccionArancelaria":null,
      "ClaveSATUnidadAduana":null,
      "ClaveSATFraccionArancelariaDescripcion":" - ",
      "ClaveSATUnidadAduanaDescripcion":" - ",
      "CveUsuarioModifico":null,
      "UsuarioModifico":null,
      "FechaUltimaModificacion":null,
      "CveClasificacionDetalle":null,
      "CostoPromedio1":0,
      "UltimoCosto":0,
      "FechaUltimaCompra":"",
      "CveTamaño":null
   },
   {
      "CvePS":362540,
      "CveClasificacion":19893,
      "Clasificacion":"Clasificación de Prueba",
      "CveUM":4185,
      "CveUnidadMedida":4185,
      "UnidadMedida":"CAJA",
      "SATClaveUnidadMedida":"BB",
      "Codigo":"66H",
      "Codigo2":null,
      "CodigoBarras":null,
      "PS":"Prueba OC Nuevo",
      "SATClavePS":null,
      "Precio":0,
      "CveTipoFactor":1,
      "Oferta":0,
      "CveSubFamilia":-1,
      "SubFamilia":"Sin Clasificación",
      "CostoPromedio":0.0000,
      "CveClasificacionPresupuesto":-1,
      "ClasificacionPresupuesto":"Sin Clasificación",
      "UsoClasificacion":3,
      "CvePuesto":null,
      "Puesto":null,
      "PSCodigo":"66H - Prueba OC Nuevo",
      "PSCodigoCompuesto":"66H - Prueba OC Nuevo",
      "IVA":-1,
      "RetIVA":0,
      "MargenGanancia":0,
      "IdCtaContVentas":0,
      "IdCtaContCompras":0,
      "IdCtaContInventarios":0,
      "AsientoContableVentas":1,
      "AsientoContableCompras":1,
      "AplicaParaConcepto":true,
      "AplicaParaVenta":true,
      "EsPaquete":false,
      "Estado":"Activo",
      "CveEstado":true,
      "Fecha":"\/Date(1547535600000)\/",
      "Usuario":"Sistema",
      "CveEmpresa":1,
      "CveMoneda":1,
      "Abreviatura":"MXN",
      "Moneda":"Pesos",
      "Inv_CveMetodoInventario":0,
      "CveTipoPS":2,
      "RowNum":2,
      "FuePorXML":1,
      "EsAdminPAQ":0,
      "PendienteEnOC":0,
      "CveClasificacionCosto":null,
      "AplicaSerieLote":null,
      "AplicaCaducidad":null,
      "Estado2":null,
      "CveClasificacion2":null,
      "AplicaParaVentaP":"Si",
      "Cantidad":1,
      "UnidadBase":true,
      "CveMarca":null,
      "AlmacenSeccion":null,
      "TipoPS":"Prod",
      "CvePSPaquete":null,
      "AplicaIEPS":false,
      "IEPSGrabaIVA":false,
      "IEPSPorcentaje":0,
      "CveConceptoContable":null,
      "CveCompuesto":-1,
      "CveSATPS":null,
      "SATClavePS1":null,
      "SATDescripcion":null,
      "Descripcion":null,
      "Inventariable":false,
      "CveProveedorCompra":null,
      "ProveedorCompra":null,
      "VentaMinima":null,
      "RetISR":null,
      "SATClaveProductoServicio":" - ",
      "PrecioMinimo":null,
      "CveFraccionArancelaria":null,
      "CveUnidadAduana":null,
      "ClaveSATFraccionArancelaria":null,
      "ClaveSATUnidadAduana":null,
      "ClaveSATFraccionArancelariaDescripcion":" - ",
      "ClaveSATUnidadAduanaDescripcion":" - ",
      "CveUsuarioModifico":null,
      "UsuarioModifico":null,
      "FechaUltimaModificacion":null,
      "CveClasificacionDetalle":null,
      "CostoPromedio1":0,
      "UltimoCosto":0,
      "FechaUltimaCompra":"",
      "CveTamaño":null
   }
]
```

I have the following json, which I get from CURL, once I want to use `$json_data = json_decode($response)` or `$json_data = json_decode($response, true)` 
I get a NULL `var_dump($json_data)`. Also tried `json_last_error($json_data)` but it's NULL too.

This rised as I was trying to iterate trough the `$json_data` and got an "Invalid argument supplied".

EDIT 1: Adding CURL to json_decode code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

$json_data = json_decode($response);
//$json_data = json_decode($response, true);

var_dump($json_data);
```

Already verified `$response` is not empty

EDIT 2: `json_last_error_msg()` throws `Syntax error` even though json linter says `Valid JSON`

Comment: Check your json with json linter.

Comment: @u_mulder Already did, returns "Valid JSON"

Comment: I tested it and it's ok http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5de96c9d97036f42e3bf873070595cb6f0e81d24

Comment: Please share your whole code, there might be a problem with your code

Comment: @catcon Added the rest

Comment: Could be a character set issue. Make sure your string is UTF-8 encoded. If it uses some other encoding, then use the appropriate conversion function, like  `utf8_encode`.

Comment: The above actually is the output of `var_dump($response)`?

Comment: Check whether you are correctly encode array from other side or not.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @trincot check your string UTF-8 encoded do it with following lines

```
$your_param = mb_convert_encoding($encoded_param_string,'UTF-8','UTF-8');
```

and also check with your php.ini max_post_limit.

Comment: If you have a string which contains special characters, json_encode or json_decode don't allow you to do that because of json has a string return type.